# place the Icon Inside of lightning input

Tags: lightning

Here is my code:

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left">
    <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_left slds-icon-text-default" iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" alternativeText="Search address"/>
    <input id="addressInput" class="slds-input" type="text" value=""/>
</div>
```

and now it looks like this:

[image]

How I can put that Icon inside of the Input? should I add some style?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: weird. your example works fine for me and icon is on the left side inside input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SLDS style, it's work for me

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-id-1">Input Label</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_left">
        <lightning:icon class="slds-icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_left slds-icon-text-default" iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" alternativeText="Search address"/>
        <input id="text-input-id-1" class="slds-input" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
```